# powershell remote jobs

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Why am I getting the error for the code below:

```
Get-Job -Id 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty childjobs | Where-Object {$_.state -eq 'Completed'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id | Receive-Job
```

> Receive-Job : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
>   the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or
>   the input and its propertie s do not match any of the parameters that
>   take pipeline input. At line:1 char:147
>   + Get-Job -Id 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty childjobs | Where-Object {$_.state -eq 'Completed'} | Select-Object
>   -ExpandProperty id | Receive-Job <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (2:PSObject) [Receive-Job], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ReceiveJobCommand

However, this line works perfectly:

```
Receive-Job (Get-Job -Id 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty childjobs | Where-Object {$_.state -eq 'Completed'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id )
```

Any tips or helpful comments on the code are appreciated.  I'm new to PowerShell.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Select-Object -ExpandProperty id` is sending a `System.Int32` which isn't what `Receive-Job` is expecting for it's ISA/HASA binding. Remove `-ExpandProperty` so you keep the `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` with the ID property.

```
Get-Job -Id 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty childjobs | Where-Object {$_.state -eq 'Completed'} | Select-Object id | Receive-Job
```

If you want to see the nitty gritty details of why a `System.Int32` didn't bind to `Receive-Job` you can use `Trace-Command`. This simplified example tries to bind a `Int32` (current process ID) to `Get-Process`.

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding  -Option All -Expression { $PID | Get-Process } -PSHost
```

The output of this command is lengthy but it shows you everything PowerShell tried to do to bind the upstream object to the downstream cmdlet.

Comment: +1 for showing him the Trace-Command, teaching him how to fish :).